# Access Nested Models from function Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to build searchFn in my ng-select based on this example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bz6drh

### Component.ts

```
  customSearchFn(term: string, item: Person) {
      term = term.toLowerCase();
      return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1 || item.department.name.toLowerCase() === term;
  }
```

### Model.ts

```
export interface Person {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    department: Array<Department>;
}

export interface Department {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
}
```

As you can see in my component I'm trying to access `item.department.name` which is not working.

Its showing `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Department[]'.`

Comment: your stackblitz is invalid

Comment: The message says it all. `department` (which should be named `departments`) is an **array** of Department objects. Arrays don't have any `name` property.

Comment: @EliyaCohen: can you try now

Comment: As JBNizet described.... you fix that, and you get it working ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a discussion with the OP, it turns out that the model was incorrect. This is the correct model:

```
export interface Person {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    department: Department;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting department.some is not a function. Will change to departments once i get it working

Comment: yeah department is an array

Comment: getting error Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'Department[]' and 'number'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198046/discussion-between-avinash-and-eliya-cohen).